# I am trying to make a countdown timer for my website and I have all the coding done, but the timer does not show up. Im doing it in dreamweaver

Tags: javascript, html, timer

Here is my HTML code i used this website to help me do the code but i still cant get the code to work. This is for my personal website that I am making for me and my friends.
 http://forum.codecall.net/topic/51639-how-to-create-a-countdown-timer-in-javascript/

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>final proj</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Timer.js" />
</head>

<body>
<div id='timer' />
<script type="text/javascript">window.onload = CreateTimer("timer",30);
</script>
<body>
<div id='timer' />
<script type="text/javascript">window.onload = CreateTimer("timer",30);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my javascript code

```
var Timer;
var TotalSeconds;

function CreateTimer(TimerID, Time) {
"use strict";
Timer = document.getElementById(TimerID);
TotalSeconds = Time;

UpdateTimer();
window.setTimeout("Tick()", 1000);  
}

function Tick() {
"use strict";
if (TotalSeconds <=0) {
    alert("Times UP!");
    return;
}
TotalSeconds -= 1;
UpdateTimer();
window.setTimeout("Tick(), 1000");
}

function UpdateTimer() {
"use strict";
var Seconds = TotalSeconds;

var Days = Math.floor(Seconds / 86400);
Seconds -= Days * (86400);

var Hours = Math.floor(Seconds / 3600);
Seconds -= Hours * (3600);
var Minutes = Math.floor(Seconds / 60);
Seconds -= Minutes * (60);

var TimeStr = ((Days > 0)) ? Days + "days ": "") + LeadingZero(Hours) + ":"                     + LeadingZero(Minutes) + ":" + LeadingZero(Seconds)

Timer.innerHTML = TimeStr;
}

function LeadingZero(Time) {

"use strict";
return (Time < 10) ? "0" + Time : + Time;
}
```

I cant get it to show up let alone countdown. I am trying to get it to display how many days,hours,minutes until a date.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The question is too long. Be specific! http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

I think this is because there is an unwanted closing parentheses on the line: `var TimeStr = ((Days)) ...` in your code which throws an error and hence nothing works.

Also, there was a problem in your `setTimeout` call as stated by @**taxicala**.

Take a look at the working snippet below:

```js
var Timer;
var TotalSeconds;

function CreateTimer(TimerID, Time) {
  Timer = document.getElementById(TimerID);
  TotalSeconds = Time;
  UpdateTimer();
  window.setTimeout(Tick, 1000);
}

function Tick() {
  if (TotalSeconds <= 0) {
    alert("Times UP!");
    return;
  }
  TotalSeconds -= 1;
  UpdateTimer();
  window.setTimeout(Tick, 1000);
}

function UpdateTimer() {
  var Seconds = TotalSeconds;
  var Days = Math.floor(Seconds / 86400);
  Seconds -= Days * 86400;
  var Hours = Math.floor(Seconds / 3600);
  Seconds -= Hours * 3600;
  var Minutes = Math.floor(Seconds / 60);
  Seconds -= Minutes * 60;
  var TimeStr = Days > 0 ? Days + "days " : "" + LeadingZero(Hours) + ":" + LeadingZero(Minutes) + ":" + LeadingZero(Seconds);
  Timer.innerHTML = TimeStr;
}

function LeadingZero(Time) {
  return (Time < 10) ? "0" + Time : +Time;
}

CreateTimer('timer', 5);
```

```html
<div id="timer" />
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

`setTimeout` receives either a reference to a function or an anonymous function as the first parameter and an integer with the amount of desirable miliseconds after which the function should be executed from the event loop as the second parameter.

This:

```
window.setTimeout("Tick(), 1000");
```

Should be:

```
window.setTimeout(Tick, 1000);
```

You are passing a string instead of the two needed parameters.

You can, however, pass a string as the first parameter, that would look like this:

```
window.setTimeout("Tick()", 1000);
```